# Creating Kubernetes secrets in Composer GKE cluster with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a way to provision secrets to the GKE cluster of Composer environment on GCP? Or more precisely, to define a Kubernetes provider based on `google_composer_environment`?

I was expecting the following to work:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "job-scheduler" {
    provider = google-beta
    name = "job-scheduler"
    region = var.region

    config {
        ...
    }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.endpoint
  client_certificate = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
  client_key = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "sa-credentials" {
  metadata {
    name = "sa-credentials"
  }

  data = {
    "secret" = "${file("${var.service_account_credentials_path}")}"
  }
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 53, in provider "kubernetes":
  53:   host = google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.endpoint

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 54, in provider "kubernetes":
  54:   client_certificate = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 55, in provider "kubernetes":
  55:   client_key = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 56, in provider "kubernetes":
  56:   cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_composer_environment.job-scheduler.config.0.gke_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Any clue would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: I guess `.config[0].` instead of `.config.0.` and so on.

Comment: @dmkvl No that doesn't work. And not according to this anyway: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/composer_environment.html#config-0-gke_cluster

Answer (score 0):

For people still wondering `gke_cluster` is a string